# How do I retrieve the values from a particular grid location in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on my first GUI project, and I have placed my code at the bottom of the post (this is a work in progress, so please bear with any ugliness or inefficiency in the code).

I'm making a GURPS character sheet which will automate character creation for my players, and then (though it isn't implemented yet) spit out a nicely formatted PDF.

The way the program works currently, I have functions which perform cost calculations based on the desired rank in an attribute, derived attribute, or skill. Pressing the "calculate" button then spits out the point cost of taking the attribute or skill at the desired level.

I generate my rows using the while-loops near the end of the class definition. The loops call functions which tell the program to create rows that carry out a certain type of calculation.

By choice, all output values appear in column 4 of each row. I would like to know if there is a way for me to easily find the value of those columns and rows without tracking the values as I go. Perhaps a method, like .grid(column,row).get() or something that would return whatever is in some specific grid location.

```
class Character_sheet:
#Our default class which will house our character sheet. 
def __init__(self):

    #Total Point Calculator?
    def sum_of_values(): 
        list = self.grid_slaves(column=3)
        sum = 0
        for each in list:
            sum += int(each["text"])
        total_cost.set(sum)


    #Generators for Rows and Columns.       
    def attr_widget_10(index):
        #The below syntax/structure works.
        def attr_10():
            cost.set((rank.get()-10)*10)
            return None
        rank = IntVar()
        rank.set(10)
        cost = IntVar()
        input = ttk.Entry(self.window, textvariable = rank).grid(column=2, row=index)
        ttk.Button(self.window, text='Calculate', command=attr_10).grid(column=3,row=index)
        ttk.Label(self.window, width=7, textvariable=cost).grid(column=4,row=index)
        return None

    def attr_widget_20(index):
        def attr_20():
            cost.set((rank.get()-10)*20)
            return None
        rank = IntVar()
        rank.set(10)
        cost = IntVar()
        input = ttk.Entry(self.window, textvariable = rank).grid(column=2, row=index)
        ttk.Button(self.window, text='Calculate', command=attr_20).grid(column=3,row=index)
        ttk.Label(self.window, width=7, textvariable=cost).grid(column=4,row=index)

    def derived_attr_widget(dictionary, index):
        return None

    def skill_widget(dictionary, index):
        return None

    def total_cost():

        return None

    #Basic window functions.
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.root.title('GURPS Character Sheet')
    self.window = ttk.Frame(self.root)
    self.window.grid()
    self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    """Core Functionality:
    Below are labels for set attributes. Each references an appropriate calculator. 
    This does not address skills. 

    For now, inputs start on row 1.
    """
    #Labels for attributes and derived attributes. 
    #ATTRIBUTES
    ttk.Label(self.window, width=10, text='Strength').grid(column=1, row=1)
    ttk.Label(self.window, width=10, text='Health').grid(column=1, row=2)
    ttk.Label(self.window, width=10, text='Intelligence').grid(column=1, row=3)
    ttk.Label(self.window, width=10, text='Dexterity').grid(column=1, row=4)
    #DERIVED ATTRIBUTES
    ttk.Label(self.window, width=10, text='HP').grid(column=1,row=5)
    ttk.Label(self.window, width=10, text='FP').grid(column=1,row=6)
    ttk.Label(self.window, width=10, text='Will').grid(column=1,row=7)
    ttk.Label(self.window, width=10, text='Perception').grid(column=1,row=8)
    ttk.Label(self.window, width=10, text='Basic Speed').grid(column=1,row=9)
    ttk.Label(self.window, width=10, text='Basic Move').grid(column=1,row=10)



    index = 1
    while index <= 2:
        attr_widget_10(index)
        index += 1
    while index <= 4:
        attr_widget_20(index)
        index += 1
    total_cost = IntVar()
    #ttk.Button(self.window, text='Total Cost', command=sum_of_values).grid(column=2,row=index+1)
    #ttk.Label(self.window, width=7, textvariable=total_cost).grid(column=4,row=index+1)


    ###CREATES WINDOW###
    self.window.mainloop()
```

Comment: better keep data in list, 2-dimensional list or dictionary and use row's index to get data. GUI should only display data not keep it.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not sure how to use the tkinter Entry widget to put data into an array, though. That's part of the reason I'm trying to do it directly in the gui.

Comment: you have big mistake in widgets - `input = Entry(..).grid()` - it assing `None` to `input` because `grid()/pack()/place()` return `None` you have to do it in two steps: `input = Entry(..)` and `input.grid()` .

Comment: you could use `lambda` in `command=lambda:attr_10(index)` to send `index` to `attr_10` an you will know in which row is this value and put it in array in correct row.

Comment: I may try the lambda syntax (I'll have to read about it); nonetheless, I still wonder whether there is some method that will return the displayed value if given a known row and column. 

Presumably, Tkinter has some way of knowing what's in a given grid position since the code works and performs the desired calculations, and displays the correct inputs and outputs. It seems reasonable that there would be a method or something which could return that value, or a tuple or dictionary of values or whatever, which correspond to the data associated with a given row and column.

Comment: @Kevin: To read the `Entry` from `row=1, column=2` use: `value = self.window.grid_slaves(row=1, column=2)[0].get()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note right off:

- stovfl's comment answers the question as it is written
- I agree fully with furas' comment about separating the gui fully from the logic. Your code should be refactored- imo- so that the Sheet GUI should be separate from the Character as an abstract collection of statistics, and also should be separate from the code which executes/manages the GUI (which is currently all handled under the umbrella `Character_sheet` class).

While I'll leave fully disentangling the `Character_sheet` to you, we can at least get you started while developing a pattern for gaining access to the values in the GUI.

Each of the first 4 rows represent statistics that the user can change and relate to a label, which you created already. Two of the statistics have a cost modifier of 10, and the other two have a modifier of 20.

```
## Place in the global space for the time being
BASE_STATISTICS = ["Strength","Health","Intelligence","Will"]
## Note that prior to Python 3.7 dictionary order was not guaranteed, so
## collections.OrderedDict would be preferable for versions before that
STATISTIC_COSTS = {"Strength":10,"Health":10,"Intelligence":20,"Will":20}
```

([collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict))

Presumably, each given Character Sheet would have its own, independent widgets and values for these statistics. Again, you should rewrite the code to be more detached, but for now we'll preserve as much of your code as possible.

```
## Place at the top of Character_sheet.__init__
## The value for each stat is a dictionary in order to store arbitrary data until the code is reworked further
self.base_stats = {stat:{} for stat in BASE_STATISTICS}
```

With these additions we now have a framework for both referring to the widget rows that you are creating and for determining what the cost modifier is for those Statistics.

```
## This will replace the Label and attr_widget_X loops and functions
## You can place it where the Attributes labels currently are, and delete both attr_widget_x functions
## enumerate pairs each element of an iterable with a sequential integer
for i,stat in enumerate(BASE_STATISTICS):
    ## These IntVars are useful, so we'll keep them around
    rank = IntVar()
    rank.set(10)
    cost = IntVar()

    ## We'll set up the gui just like you did, just with a minor tweak
    ttk.Label(self.window, width=10, text=stat).grid(column=1, row=i)
    ttk.Entry(self.window, textvariable = rank).grid(column=2, row=i)
    ## I've removed the Generate button for reasons I'll get into below
    ttk.Label(self.window, width=7, textvariable=cost).grid(column=3,row=i)

    ## Here we save all our references so that we can come back to them later
    ## self.base_stats[stat]['row'] will tell us which row of the grid the widgets are located
    ## self.base_stats[stat]['rank'] will now give us direct access to the rank IntVar at all times
    ## self.base_stats[stat]['cost'] likewise gives us easy access to the cost IntVar whenever we need it
    self.base_stats[stat].update({'row':i,'rank': rank,'cost':cost})
```

([enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate))

Tkinter gives you access to different signal types; specifically for our uses, `tkinter Variables` can be bound using their [trace method](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm). By using the `'w'` mode, whenever the `Variable` changes, the given callback (function) will be called. Using this we can make the GUI more responsive by getting rid of the need to constantly hit the `Generate Button`.

```
## This should go right after "cost = IntVar()"
## The lambda statement here is technically the function that is being passed to trace
## The lambda itself is capturing all information it gets passed as e
## stat = stat creates a reference within the lambda definition to the current value of stat
## (as you iterate, the stat value in the local scope will change, so we need to preserve it)
## and then calling self.updatestat and passing that the stat we're updating.
rank.trace('w',lambda *e,stat = stat: self.updatestat(stat))
```

([lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions))

And now we can add `Character_sheet.updatestat` so it actually functions:

```
def updatestat(self,stat):
    """ Queries the current value of the stat's rank and then sets the cost appropriately """
    ## Get the IntVar for the given stat from your stats dict
    rankvar = self.base_stats[stat]['rank']
    ## Since we're using an Entry (instead of e.g.- a spinbox), there's
    ## no garauntee that it contains a valid integer, so we use try/except
    ## to catch the mistake
    try:
        rank = rankvar.get()
        rank = int(rank)
    except:
        ## We'll reset the value if it's invalid
        rank = 10
        rankvar.set(rank)

    ## Use STATISTIC_COSTS to determine the cost modifier
    ## Calculate cost
    cost = (rank - 10)*STATISTIC_COSTS[stat]

    ## find our IntVar for the given stat
    costvar = self.base_stats[stat]['cost']
    ## Set it to cost
    costvar.set(cost)

    ## Note that "return None" is the implicit default
```

And that gets you just a little closer to getting your GUI separated from your programming logic while allowing you to reference those values in the rows and columns like you were trying to do (i.e.- `self.stats['Strength']['rank'].get()`)

Comment: This is an absolutely amazingly helpful answer. I've actually already made significant changes to the GUI, as I continue to learn more about tkinter and how it works, but your suggestions have pretty much given me a lot of exactly what I wanted, like a more responsive GUI. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)